# Why is ResultSet.getDate() returning null but returns a valid date string when using ResultSet.getString()?

Tags: java, oracle, date

Worth mentioning I'm working with legacy code here, so I need to get this date as a `java.sql.Date` object.

Here is the code in question. I'm trying to retrieve the birthdate in an Oracle SQL database as a `java.sql.Date` object, where the table column is a nullable DATE field. The value that would be returned is a birthdate of 09/18/1962.

```
    public java.sql.Date getBirthdate(int key, DataManager oDM) throws Exception
    {
        String sSQL = "SELECT BIRTH_DATE FROM PEOPLE WHERE PERSON_KEY = ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = oDM.getConnection().prepareStatement(sSQL);
        pstmt.setInt(1, key);
        ResultSet oResultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
        java.sql.Date birthDate = null;
        String birthDateString = "";

        if (!oResultSet.next())
        {
            throw new Exception("Key did not return a birth date");
        }
        else
        {
            birthDate = oResultSet.getDate("BIRTH_DATE");
            birthDateString = oResultSet.getString("BIRTH_DATE");
        }
        
        oResultSet.close();
        pstmt.close();

        java.sql.Date birthDateParsed = java.sql.Date.valueOf(birthDateString.substring(0, 10));

        return birthDate;
    }
```

Now when I grab the value as a `String` from `ResultSet.getString()`, it returns the expected string value in `YYYY-MM-dd` format with a timestamp. When I use `ResultSet.getDate()`, it returns a null date. Interestingly enough, when I get the substring of the returned string to convert it to a `java.sql.Date` object using `java.sql.Date.valueOf()`, it STILL returns a null date object.

To lay it out with debug values, where the person's birthdate is 09/18/1962 on a nullable OracleSQL date field, here are the variable values.

`birthDate` is `NULL`

`birthDateString.substring(0,10)` is `1962-09-18`

`birthDateParsed` is `NULL`

What am I missing that I can't get the date value into a `java.sql.Date` object?

Comment: can you try Result.getTimestamp()?

Comment: "birthDateParsed is NULL" - do you mean right before `return birthDate;` `birthDateParsed` is `null`? This shouldn't happen as `java.sql.Date.valueOf(...)` should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the substring was null or the date couldn't be parsed.

Comment: You want to `parse()` String  `birthDateString` variable to date

Comment: @xerx593 where is that stated? A date before epoch (1970-01-01 00:00,000 GMT) which I assume you're referring to as the range could be represented as a negative number of milliseconds. It also wouldn't make sense to limit the range for this class to dates after 1970.

Comment: yes, sorry for me (jdk 17), `String dateStr = "1962-09-18";System.out.println(java.sql.Date.valueOf(dateStr));` *prints*: `1962-09-18`

Comment: @Thomas that is what my debugger shows. Maybe it's an issue with the debugger? Either way, a valid date value is not being returned based on the website functionality.

Comment: What is the column type in your database ? `DATE` or `DATETIME` ?

Comment: Why do you do `.substring(0,10)` ? If it's a `DATE` the returned String is already 10 char long

Comment: I doubt there's an issue with your debugger (very unlikely) but maybe with how you used it. Did you stop at the return statement? Did you make sure the code that's running is the code you're debugging?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `java.sql.Date.valueOf("1962-09-18")` returns `1962-09-18`  on my Java. So not `null`.

Comment: @vincrichaud It’s probably an Oracle thing. IIRC, the `date` data type on Oracle may include a time of day (with limited precision). So I suppose you could get a string that is longer than 10 chars. Opposite other database engines.

Comment: The way I read the source code `java.sql.Date.valueOf()` *cannot* return `null`. It would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead.

Comment: When your compiler sees that you are never using the value of `birthDateParsed`, it may decide not to store any value into it. So in your debugger you will see `null`. This does not mean that `valueOf()` returned `null`.